# Post Image alt text not appearing in WordPress website

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, seo

We have a free classified website [Asan Classifieds](https://www.asan.com.pk/), In WordPress we updated website to Advanced Custom Fields v5.8.1! After that image alt text not showing up, even we cannot edit image, my question is how to fix this problem? thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in error log or browser console?

Answer (score -1):

WordPress content is "frozen". That is, if you add an alt on an image after posting an article with the image, the alt attribute will not be updated on its own.
If you ever use Gutenberg, it is easy to be able to make a regex and update your article on the fly.
You can do this with the ImageSEO plugin without having to update each of your articles.